# DRF serializer for questions that depend on multiple objects

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am trying to write a serializer which allows users to submit the answers to a quiz. However, the questions that should be answered depend on two separate things in the database. So, let's say we have these models:-

```
class Day(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
```

```
class Quiz(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
```

```
class QuizQuestion(models.Model):
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz, related_name="questions")
    days = models.ManyToManyField(Day, related_name="questions")
    question = models.CharField()
```

```
class QuizCompletion(models.Model):
    completed_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz)
```

```
class QuizAnswer(models.Model):
    quizquestion = models.ForeignKey(QuizQuestion)
    quizcompletion = models.ForeignKey(related_name="answers", QuizCompletion)
    answer = models.CharField()
```

So, to find the questions that the user has to answer for a particular quiz for a particular day, you'd need to do something like:-

```
questions = quiz.questions.filter(days__id=day.id)
```

I'm trying to create the serializer for submitting the answers to such a quiz so that it will check whether all of the questions have been answered.

What is the best way to write this serializer?

The days thing is the thing that's confusing me. Do I need a URL that includes BOTH the quiz ID and the day ID, so that I can get the right questions?

```
class QuizCompletionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    quiz = QuizSerializer()
    answers = QuizAnswerSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = QuizCompletion
        fields = ["completed_by", "quiz", "answers"]

    def validate_answers(self, answers):
        # iterate through this quiz's questions for this day, checking that we have an answer for each one
        # how do I get the quiz and the day for this method?
```

Or can I somehow put the day into the serializer and do something else?